# Move products and attributes from 1.4 db dump

Tags: database

I have a db dump from an old magento installation.

From this I would like to move all products and attributes.

The db dump was taked from a 1.4 instllation and it will be going to a 1.7

This is not an upgrade, i want to move the data between databases.

Can anyone offer advice on how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving attributes to a new installation can me done manually or with some automation: http://alanstorm.com/magento_attribute_migration_generator

As for moving the products, you can run a Dataflow export and an import if you don't have any complex products. The 1.4 dataflow exporter should be compatible with the 1.7 dataflow importer (it isn't compatible with the Mage_ImportExport module).

**Old answer:**

I'd suggest to set up the 1.4 installation so it works there and upgrade the installation from there.

There seem to be similar questions, please take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662347/how-to-upgrade-magento-1-4-1-1-to-1-7-0-2

Comment: unfortunately this will not be possible.  In this specific situation it just isnt an option

Comment: Oh I see, this isn't really easy to do, i've edited my answer.